# Windows phone 10 UWP app Deployment error

Tags: windows, emulation, windows-10, uwp

I am facing the following error, while deploying the package to windows phone device or emulator.

**Development specs:** Windows 10 Pro Insider preview. Visual Studio Community edition.

> Error: Verify the project is selected to be deployed in the solution configuration manager, or deploy it explictly by clicking on the deploy commands in the build menu.

Tried all the possible ways of solving. Can any one suggest a solution for this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue.  Could not get it to work with a new project.  I would up doing the recovery option in the control panel to install a fresh copy of windows leaving my files to fix it.  I think I had something left on my computer from the beta

Comment: Tried repair but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked that you are using the Visual Studio Community RTM version from your Screenshot, but based on this article(https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/29/release-dates-and-compatibility-visual-studio-2015-and-windows-10-sdk/), Windows 10 preview version will not work with the Visual Studio 2015 RTM version when creating the UWP app, so you will meet error, please try to upgrade your Windows 10 Pro Insider preview to **Windows 10 RTM**, besides the Windows 10 Pro Insider preview has a lot of bugs.